# Match word only if no given prefix with arbitrary number of spaces

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am trying to create a regex which would match the word `bar` except when there is the word `foo` behind.

I found that negative lookbehind could handle this, but the problem is that there is an arbitrary number of characters belonging to the expression `[\s\-/]` between `foo` and `bar`.

And unfortunately negative lookbehind does not support arbitrary length.

So the pattern `(?<!foo[\s\-/]*)bar` is not valid.

Do you know a regex technique that can overcome this problem?

Comment: Just to point out: Not having support for arbitrary lookahead/lookbehind lengths is not a regex limitation in general but a limitation in certain regex implementations. For example [this](https://regex101.com/r/NHiquk/1) works for JavaScript but basically none of the other choices of regex implementation so it might be helpful to tag the specific flavour of regex you're using

Comment: @apokryfos I am using `re` in python3, which does not support it (apparently). And I can't really change the package I use because it would imply a lot of changes in my code...

Comment: I do not think  anything will need changing if you install PyPi regex module (`pip install regex`) and then use `import regex as re`. Then, `re.findall(r'(?<!\bfoo\b.*?)\bbar\b', text)` will work.

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be :

```
import re

c = re.compile(r'^(?!.*foo.*bar).*(bar).*$')

lst = ['bar', 'hi bar', 'foo   bar', 'foobar', 'hiiifoohiiibar']

for i in lst:
    match_obj = c.match(i)
    if match_obj:
        print(match_obj.group(), '|', match_obj.group(1))
```

output :

```
bar | bar
hi bar | bar
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/SHWjF6/1)

**Explanation** : First we check the whole string to see if there is both `'foo'` and `'bar'` in the string(first foo then bar) with `(?!.*foo.*bar)`. This is a *negative lookahead assertion*, if this pair doesn't exist, we can proceed.

Next that we are sure there isn't any `foo` before `bar`, we get all the string including `bar`. We put that in a group so that we can retrieve it via `group(1)`.

Comment: This works, but note that it will only capture the last occurrence of bar in group 1.

Answer (score 2):

One technique is to use the PyPi regex-module instead of the standard re-module. As I've read your query it looks like you would want to validate any string with the word "bar" in there unless it's preceded by the word "foo" along with an arbitrairy number of spaces and hyphens. If that's correct you can use:

```
(?<!foo[\s-]*)bar
```

Meaning; a negative lookbehind that starts with 'foo' and contains 0+ times a whitespace-character and/or hyphens. Here is some sample code:

```
import regex as re
lst = ['foobar', 'foo   -   bar', 'foo- -bar', 'foodbar']
for i in lst:
    if re.search(r'(?<!foo[\s-]*)bar', i):
        print(i)
```

Prints:

```
foodbar
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need this [pip package regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) - it would not work with the default `re`:

```
foo\s*+bar(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|bar
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gczzaF/1/)

An example invocation in the interpreter:

```
>>> import regex
>>> print(regex.search(r'foo\s*+bar(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|bar', 'fdfdf foo bar fdfdf foo bar bar'))
<regex.Match object; span=(28, 31), match='bar'>
```

Comment: Or to also match the characters from the question, it might be `foo[\s/-]*bar(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|bar`

Answer (score 1):

My solution is simple: There are two parts to the test:

1. If "bar" is in the text
2. If not ("bar", plus `[\s\-/]`, plus "foo")

Putting it into code:

```py
import re

data = [
    # Good
    "bar and not foo",
    "bar alone",

    # Bad
    "bar - foo",
    "barfoo",
    "bar foo",
    "bar / foo",
]


for text in data:
    if "bar" in text and not re.match(r"bar[\s\-/]*foo", text):
        print(text)
```

Output:

```
bar and not foo
bar alone
```

In general, I stay away from regular expression because it is hard to understand. I only use it when I must.